# Kong admin to fetch services from multiple namespaces

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, kong, kong-ingress

I have kong installed in my cluster in the kong-istio namespace, I have kong-admin, kong-proxy, kong-manager services running. I am using enterprise image for the kong setup.

Used helm chart to install Kong (https://github.com/Kong/charts/tree/main/charts/kong)

[image: Cluster kong services]

I can access the Kong manager as I am using external PSQL and can create routes and plugins.

The real question is since I have deployed it in my kong-istio namespace. I have multiple microservices deployed in different namespaces. When I hit my kong admin URL I am only getting services running in the kong-istio namespace and not from other namespaces.

FYI - In my cluster istio-service mesh is also defined that is used for internal service communication.

My values.yaml file.

database: "postgres"
pg_host: ""
pg_port: 
pg_user: kong_qa_app
pg_password: 
pg_timeout : 5000
pg_database : kong_qa